# Implementing ArrayList in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, arraylist

I know that there is no support for Generics in Blackberry, but i want to use ArrayList in Blackberry. I have read that its possible to implement ArrayList in Blackberry, i know that few people have done that. Can any one please help me, by telling me which all classes to use from java.util package in order to implement ArrayList in Blackberry. Its possible by coping the required classes from java.util package in your own BB package and then use that implementation. But i am not sure which all classes to copy.

Thanks in Advance.
Regards,
Varun

Comment: I think you are coming from android; if not or yes better to use Vector to store Objects/string values;

Comment: Thanks for responding, but i want to use Generics i.e. ArrayList of my custom Objects (POJOs). That is not supported in Blackberry. Any suggestions, how to implement that in BB. I want something like ArrayList of (POJOs) or even something like Vector of (POJOs) will also work. Do you know how to do that?

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: Forget. You can't have generics in BlackBerry.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `Vector` instead of `ArrayList`. From an API perspective, the two classes are very similar.

You will need to keep the following in mind

Vectors are synchronized. Any method that uses the Vector's contents is thread safe. `ArrayList`, on the other hand, is unsynchronized,and therefore, not thread safe. There fore using synchronization will incur a performance hit.

Comment: Thanks all for responding, but i want to use Generics i.e. ArrayList of my custom Objects (POJOs). That is not supported in Blackberry. Any suggestions, how to implement that in BB. I want something like ArrayList of (POJOs) or even something like Vector of (POJOs) will also work. Does any body know how to do that?

Thanks,
Varun

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` is effectively just a wrapper for a standard Object array and it's not too tricky to implement.  It works just like a standard array, until it gets full.  Then it creates a new array which is larger by a fixed factor than the previous one, then it copies all the elements across to the new array.

If you want to implement one yourself, then it's probably worth checking out the source for the standard Java class: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but i want to use Generics i.e. ArrayList of my custom Objects (POJOs). That is not supported in Blackberry. Any suggestions, how to implement that in BB. I want something like ArrayList of (POJOs) or even something like Vector of (POJOs) will also work. Do you know how to do that?

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: I don't think that's very easy!  Generics is part of the language, so it's not possible to just bolt it on.  You could just cheat and do Java 1.4 style generics, e.g. `Vector/*<TypeToBeStored>*/ v;`; but of course it doesn't actually do anything!